# Multiple Owl Carousels on the same page with navigation problem

Tags: customization, loop, navigation

The index page of my Wordpress includes a loop dividing my posts per months. To display each month I'm using Owl Carousel 2. I'm experiencing some difficulties with the navigation of each carousel/month. Indeed, my navigation are two buttons "Next" and "Prev", and each time I click them it activates the nav for all the carousels on the page.

I found an answer that matches to the same issue, but the problem is still giving me some headaches. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054606/jquery-each-function-for-multiple-carousels-next-prev-identifier-issue)

Here is the JS code for the carousels:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var carouselCount = 0;

  $('.index-carousel').each(function() {

    $(this).attr("id", "owl-carousel-" + carouselCount);

    var carouselID = $('#owl-carousel-' + carouselCount);

    carouselID.owlCarousel({
      loop:false,
      margin:2,
      autoplay:false,
      responsiveClass:true,
      responsive:{
          0:{
              items:1,
              nav:false
          },
          700:{
              items:2,
              nav:false
          }
      }
    });


    $('.monthly-row').parent().find(".carousel-nav.next").click(function(){
      carouselID.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    });
    $('.monthly-row').parent().find(".carousel-nav.prev").click(function(){
      carouselID.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
    });

    carouselCount++;
  }); 
});
```

Thank you for your help!